# How to realise sound effect in console-based effect for each char

Tags: c#

How to realize sound effects in console-based effect for each char.
in example: [Ace Attorney dialogues](https://youtu.be/IDNuz_VFJtU)
I have a loop that slowly prints chars

```
static void PrintSlow(string str)
{
    foreach (char c in str)
    {
        Console.Write(c);
        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }
}
```

I've tried to change `Console.Write("\a" + c);` but it's not worked.

P.S I can accept answers in Russian

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement sound in a C# Console Application correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48311157/how-to-implement-sound-in-a-c-sharp-console-application-correctly)

Comment: I'm still a beginner, I think this option is still too complicated for me, in any case, thank you for your help

Comment: there is no simple option. console is managed by the OS.

Comment: Console.Beep(37, 500);